# Lowercase cyrillic {QUERY_STRING}

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

On my site i have links like:

```
site.com/search.php?str=СТРОКА
site.com/search.php?str=Строка
```

I want to make them like:

```
site.com/search.php?str=строка
```

i.e. I want to lowercase {QUERY_STRING}

How I can do this? **I can't use RewriteMap!**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you not able to use RewriteMap?

Comment: @Bobulous, My site is on a simple shared hosting, so there is no way to declare RewriteMap in httpd.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have links with ciryllic query_string like this:

```
site.com/search.php?str=СТРОКА
site.com/search.php?str=Строка
```

And you want to make them like e.g. lowercase it

```
site.com/search.php?str=строка
```

And you can't use RewriteMap, follow these steps:

**1) Add to .htaccess those rows:**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} %D0%([AF].)
RewriteRule (.*) rewrite-strtolower.php?rewrite-strtolower-url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

%D0%([9A].)|(81) - detecting [А-Я]

**2) Place rewrite-strtolower.php nearly of .htacces**

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    function myUrlEncode($string) {
        $entities = array('%21', '%2A', '%27', '%28', '%29', '%3B', '%3A', '%40', '%26', '%3D', '%2B', '%24', '%2C', '%2F', '%3F', '%25', '%23', '%5B', '%5D');
        $replacements = array('!', '*', "'", "(", ")", ";", ":", "@", "&", "=", "+", "$", ",", "/", "?", "%", "#", "[", "]");
        return str_replace($entities, $replacements, urlencode($string));
    }

    if(isset($_GET['rewrite-strtolower-url'])) {     
        $url = $_GET['rewrite-strtolower-url'];
        unset($_GET['rewrite-strtolower-url']);
        $params = http_build_query($_GET);
        if(strlen($params)) {         
            $params = '?' . myUrlEncode(mb_strtolower(urldecode($params),"UTF-8"));
        }
        header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . $url . $params, true, 301);
       exit;
    } 
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    die('Unable to convert the URL to lowercase. You must supply a URL to work upon.');
?>
```

**3) Profit**